# why kfifo is Circular queue in some blogs

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

Does kfifo is Circlar queue?

In Circlar queue WIKI (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) said "**it were connected end-to-end.**". but in  linux-4.16.12\lib\kfifo.c

```
int __kfifo_init(struct __kfifo *fifo, void *buffer,
        unsigned int size, size_t esize)
{
    size /= esize;

    size = roundup_pow_of_two(size);

    fifo->in = 0;
    fifo->out = 0;
    fifo->esize = esize;
    fifo->data = buffer;

    if (size < 2) {
        fifo->mask = 0;
        return -EINVAL;
    }
    fifo->mask = size - 1;

    return 0;
}
```

I don't find the start pointer point to the end pointer, so :

1) Does kfifo is Circlar queue?

2) if yes, how to prove it ?

Comment: As described in [Linux Device Drivers chapter 5](https://static.lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch05.pdf) `kfifo` is a circular buffer (page 124) `there is a generic circular buffer implementation available in
the kernel; see <linux/kfifo.h> for information on how to use it.`

Comment: Linux kfifo is a bit convoluted if this is the first time you are looking at such code, but the reason why it works as a circular buffer is that it always applies the bitwise mask (`kfifo.mask`) to `in` and `out` before accessing the array. This means that the length of this fifo must always be a power of 2 (hence the call to `roundup_pow_of_two`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Wikipedia page you mentioned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) states that a circular buffer behaves *as if* the buffer was connected end to end. In practice, circular buffer is simply an array of a certain fixed length, with two index pointers (usually called `head` and `tail`, or `in` and `out`) representing the "boundaries" of the written data. To avoid writing outside the buffer bounds, all arithmetic operations on these indices are done [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) length of the buffer.

Usually, the meaning of the pointers is:

- `head` or `in` index, indicates the next available slot for writing, and
- `tail` or `out` index, indicates the last read ("removed") slot.

There are also two boundary states:

- if `tail` is equal to `head`, then the buffer is empty.
- if incrementing the `tail` modulo buffer length would make `tail` and `head` equal, then the buffer is full.

Most implementations will keep the indices within the buffer bounds using one of these approaches:

```
// check if index overflowed and reset
int fifo_increment_index(struct fifo *fifo, int index)
{
     index = index + 1; 
     if (index > fifo->capacity)
         index = 0;
     return index;
}

// use the modulo operator (slower due to division,
// although it avoids branching)
int fifo_increment_index(struct fifo *fifo, int index)
{
     index = (index + 1) % fifo->capacity; // modulo
     return index;
}

// use a bitwise mask (in most cases the fastest approach),
// but works ONLY if capacity is a power of 2
int fifo_increment_index(struct fifo *fifo, int index)
{
     // if capacity is 1024 (0x400), then
     // mask will be 1023 (0x3FF)

     index = (index + 1) & fifo->mask; // bitwise and
     return index;
}
```

Linux kfifo uses the last approach (bitwise masking), which is why it always [ensures that the capacity is a power of two](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.20-rc4/lib/kfifo.c#L45) inside the init function (`size = roundup_pow_of_two(size)`).

However, it does not reset the indices as soon as they change, but rather masks them on each access to the buffer:

```
#define __KFIFO_PEEK(data, out, mask) ( (data)[(out) & (mask)] )
#define __KFIFO_POKE(data, in, mask, val) ( (data)[(in) & (mask)] = (unsigned char)(val) )
```

For a `uint8_t` buffer, the `__KFIFO_PEEK` macro is basically:

```
static inline uint8_t kfifo_peek(struct __kfifo *fifo)
{
     int index = fifo->out & fifo->mask;
     return fifo->data[index];
}
```

Comment: first of all. thanks for your detailed answer, but I have a question about mask of kfifo. Why  'index = (index + 1) & fifo->mask;'  better than    'index = index + 1;'?

Comment: @xiaoyuyang: you mean why it's better than `if (index > fifo->capacity)`? The reason is that modern processors have [large pipelines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipelining#Illustrated_example) which are filled with instructions even before the CPU gets time to process them. Whenever the CPU gets to a conditional branch, it has to predict where the branch will jump, and a misprediction means it will have to drop whatever it's in the pipeline and start over again. So it often makes sense to replace the conditional (`if`) with a branchless instruction.

Comment: Regarding `%` vs `&`, the bitwise `&` is usually a single CPU instruction, while `%` often needs a division, which can be several instructions. If you are using `%` with a constant literal, then most optimizing compilers will generate more efficient code instead of division, but they can hardly beat a single `&` instruction.